# using respond_to do |format| format.js to show a message inside of a modal after photo is favorited inside a modal?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The web user has a modal open with a picture showing, they click on:

**photos/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to favorite_photo_path("#{photo.id}"), method: :put do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
<% end %>
```

The end goal is to keep the user inside of the modal, with a message shown inside of the modal, "You have successfully favorited this photo"... I am testing this out in the middle of the controller where I call `respond_to do...` However, when the glyphicon is clicked the model is updated however browser ends up stuck on `www.examples.com/photos/1/favorite`

**Routes**

```
resources :photos do
  match :favorite, on: :member, via: [:put, :delete]
end
```

**PhotosController**

```
def favorite
  @photo = Photo.find params[:id]
    if request.put?
     response = current_user.favorite_photos.new(photo: @photo)
     if !response.valid?  
      redirect_to :back, notice: response.errors.full_messages
     else
      response.save
        respond_to do |format| 
          format.js
        end
     end
    else request.delete?
      current_user.favorites.delete(@photo)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited this photo' 
    end 
  end
```

**photos/favorite.js.erb**

```
 $('.modal-dialog.photo>.message').html('You have successfully favorited this photo');
```

When html { redirect_to :back } is used, it closes the modal.

Comment: You wrote `else request.delete?`, did you mean `elsif request.delete?`?

Comment: does it change the code in someway?

Comment: In your case, no... but only because you're doing `if request.put?`. The statement `else request.delete?` does not get evaluated the way you think. To add more conditions to an if statement you must use `elsif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To utilize the JavaScript response, you will need to add the `remote: true` option to your link.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

If you want to handle this via AJAX, don't use redirect back.

Also use `flash.now` for AJAX.

Instead handle both scenarios in you're JavaScript file.

```
# app/views/photos/favorite.js.erb     
<% if flash.now[:notice] %>
   $('.modal-dialog.photo>.message').html("<%= j flash.now[:notice] %>")
<% else %>
  $('.modal-dialog.photo>.message').html("<%= j flash.now[:alert] %>")
<% end %>

# app/views/photo/unfavorite.js.erb
<% if flash.now[:notice] %>
  $('.modal-dialog.photo>.message').html("<%= j flash.now[:notice] %>")
<% end %>
```

It kind of goes that `notice` is like success and `alert` are error.

And change your controller to this:

```
def favorite
  @photo = Photo.find params[:id]
  favorite_photo = current_user.favorites.build(photo: @photo)

  if favorite_photo.save
    flash.now[:notice] = 'You successfully favorited this photo'
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = favorite_photo.errors.full_messages
  end
  respond_to :js
end

def unfavorite
  @photo = Photo.find params[:id]
  current_user.favorites.delete(@photo)
  flash.now[:notice] = 'You successfully unfavorited this photo'
  respond_to :js
end
```

And your routes to match this configuration.

I'd `POST` to favorite and `DELETE` to unfavorite due to the DB implications of each.

Currently you can only pass `notice` and `alert` to a `render` or `redirect_to`. But you can defined your own flash types. But don't constrain yourself by using only these two.

```
if success
  flash[:success] = "Something good"
else
  flash[:error] = "Something bad"
end
```

Comment: What does controller look like so that js will know if flash[:notice]? Once it hits respond_to in the controller doesn't the js trigger and ignore the rest of the controller code? Do I need to write respond_to multiple times? Right now after you reminded me about remote true I just moved all the code to the js file and then left the rest of the code in html { }